# Select max number group by initial letter in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column say, `Process` in MySQL table with values like A1,A2,..A100, B5,B7..B700, C2,C3...C900 each in separate row. I want to find max number from each initial. so output will be as

```
A100, B700,C900
```

I am using below query

```
select MAX(process) as max_process
from tablename
group by substr(process,1,1)
```

but it don't gives me max number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select MAX(cast(substr(process,2,length(process)-1) as signed)) as max_process
from tablename
group by substr(process,1,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select prefix, max(number) `max` from (
  select substring(process, 1, 1) prefix,
         cast(substring(process, 2, 100) as signed) number
  from MyTable
) a group by prefix;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a43a8/6)

Answer (score 0):

You get the 1st char of process with `left(process, 1)` and the numeric part with `substring(process, 2)`. 
Then by simply adding `0` to the numeric part you convert it to a number:

```
select
  left(process, 1) process1, 
  max(substring(process, 2) + 0) max_process
from tablename
group by process1
```